# Configuring SSL for an AWS autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

My app is divided into a web app and an API server. Both are hosted on separate AWS instances. The API server is enabled for autoscaling.

This question is with regard to my API server. What's the way to configure a free SSL certificate with auto-renewals (e.g. the one from Let's Encrypt) over its autoscaling group?

Configuring it on one machine is trivial, however I can't wrap my head around doing it for an entire autoscaling group. I haven't been able to find docs that refer to this scenario either. Can you point out everything step by step?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put an ALB before the Auto Scaling Group, use ACM to generate free SSL certificate, and load those certs in ALB. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-billing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your ASG in an ALB & add port 443 (HTTPS) as the listener for it. Refer this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html).

You can get free SSL from AWS itself in ACM. Issue it for you domain name & assign it to ALB.

Also, ACM keeps renewing automatically after expiration for free & without any inputs from user.